# Unable to modify the .Text property of a cell

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

```
Sub ex2()
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("a2").Text = "Anil"
End Sub
```

I want to copy the data Anil into cell a2, but I am getting RUN time error saying:

> Unable to set the Text property of the Range class.

Can any one advice how to work using TEXT METHOD?

Answer (score 17):

`.Text` is read only.

To set cell values you use the `.Value` property.

Comment: Can you please make the difference between Text and Value?

Answer (score 5):

Use the .Value property and not the .Text:

```
Sub ex2()
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("a2").Value = "Anil"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the following link, you should be using the Value method...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg192736(v=office.14).aspx

```
Sub ex2()
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("a2").Value = "Anil"
End Sub
```